# ScrollMagic - Mousewheel and Trackpad Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm using ScrollMagic to do parallax section scrolling following this [tutorial](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/parallax_sections.html). I have it working visually, but now the page has stopped scrolling when using the mouse wheel or the track pad. The only way that it will scroll is by dragging the scroll bar on the right.

**main.css**

```
.parallaxParent {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.parallaxParent > * {
    height: 200%;
    position: relative;
    top: -100%;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
    ...
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="parallax1" class="parallaxParent picture-frame">
    <div style="background-image: url(../images/website/some-image.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-text-frame text-align-center">
        blah blah blah        
    </div>

    <!-- Include ScrollMagic and GSAP plugin -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.3/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.3/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scroll_magic.js"></script>

</body>
```

**scroll_magic.js**

```
// init controller
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({globalSceneOptions: {triggerHook: "onEnter", duration: "200%"}});

// build scenes
new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#parallax1"})
                .setTween("#parallax1 > div", {y: "80%", ease: Linear.easeNone})
                .addIndicators()
                .addTo(controller);

new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#parallax2"})
                .setTween("#parallax2 > div", {y: "80%", ease: Linear.easeNone})
                .addIndicators()
                .addTo(controller);

new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#parallax3"})
                .setTween("#parallax3 > div", {y: "80%", ease: Linear.easeNone})
                .addIndicators()
                .addTo(controller);
```

This all follows their tutorial, which works perfectly. Clearly I've done something wrong, but I don't know what. The problem manifests in both Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks for any advice!

**EDIT**

It was pointed out to me that there is some error logging in the console that I hadn't noticed. All of the errors that generate on the page load are essentially debugging errors that I am fine with. However, when I attempt to scroll the page with my mousewheel, all of a sudden this error starts to get generated literally hundreds of times:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'scrollTo' on 'Window': 2
>   arguments required, but only 0 present.

and its source is `TweenMax.min.js:16`

Did some digging into this and found a couple of [posts](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/issues/57). It looks like I am missing a GreenSock plugin, but I thought that my script tags should have picked this up. I've tried a number of things to get this plugin, but nothing is working. For example, I tried adding this line:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.0/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know how I can include this plugin into my project? I'd strongly prefer to do it with an external reference rather than copying an entire project onto my server.

Comment: Do you have a live demo maybe? Hard to debug like this...

Comment: The console is reporting a few errors related to the parallax. It says `plugins/debug.addIndicator.js` is missing. And that a few elements are not found - `#parallax` with the numbers 3-5 appended...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Can't believe that I took my eye off the console output and didn't notice that. Those errors are all debugging output that I'm fine with. However, when I start scrolling with the mousewheel, Hundreds of identical errors generate. I can't figure out how to resolve this error, so I edited my post to explain this behavior.

Comment: Probably unrelated but jQuery is loaded three times - and the scripts at the bottom are outside `</body>`.

Comment: `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js`

Comment: I think you're linking to the wrong scrollTo plugin, try the one above instead...

Comment: That was it. I thought that I had tried that one, but obviously not. Thanks a lot. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Good it got solved, glad I could help. Appreciate the offer but I think you figured it out yourself mostly. I just happened to recognise that plugin as being jQuery instead of GSAP and then googled a bit. The issue may also be somewhat too specific for future users to find it. And if they do, the solution's in the comments for them anyway. Taken all that, I'm okay with not gaining any rep for it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With full credit to @Shikkediel in the comments above, the solution here was simply to add this line just before the `</body>` tag (where the other script tags already existed):

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
```

So, the complete group of scripts related to making ScrollMagic work with parallax sections is this (ignoring debugging tags for debugging):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include ScrollMagic and GSAP plugin -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.3/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.3/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll_magic.js"></script>
```